# Query executes in phpmyadmin but not in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this query which executes on PHPMYADMIN but not in PHP code in Wordpress:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS LoopDemo; 
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS SPLIT_STR(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), p INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p -1)) + 1), delim, '');
```

This the PHP:

```php
$create_func = $wpdb->prepare("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS LoopDemo; CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS SPLIT_STR(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), p INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p -1)) + 1), delim, '');"); 
$saved = $wpdb->get_results($create_func);
```

This is the error that is thrown:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS SPLIT_STR(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), p INT' at line 1] 
>   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS LoopDemo; CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS SPLIT_STR(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), p INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p -1)) + 1), delim, '');

Comment: Hi Besart, Can you show the query in the php code?

Comment: How are you implementing the query in wordpress, plz show

Comment: This is the php code : $create_func = $wpdb->prepare("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS LoopDemo; CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS SPLIT_STR(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), p INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, p -1)) + 1), delim, '');"); $saved = $wpdb->get_results($create_func);

Comment: Seems like multiple statements cannot be used in one go. Try to issue each statement on its own and see if that works.

Comment: Yes it works, but I need to execute the query in one go.

Comment: Your actual problem is only executing multiple queries in wp, that's a duplicate. Here is a good answer, not exactly what you demand, but will solve it elegantly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247015/complex-wordpress-query-using-multiple-queries#answer-18329598

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex Wordpress query using multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247015/complex-wordpress-query-using-multiple-queries)