# WordPress - How to run complex query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a rather long and complicated SQL query.
I want to use commands like `SET @varible`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`, `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`, `case when`, etc.

I need this data from the DB to construct the page.
It works well via the myphpadmin, but I get no results using:
`$wpdb->get_results ( $query );`

Which I guess isn't the correct function to execute this one. How do I approach it correctly?

How do you execute queries that have more than just a simple `select`?

Sorry for the long text, here is the full query: [query](https://github.com/yonish3/wp_sql/blob/7d9f69d819afccb05f5af93e456febf74b76b358/sql)

Deferentially from this answer: [WordPress - How to run complex query using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692112/wordpress-how-to-run-complex-query-using-php?noredirect=1#comment123186583_69692112)

I don't think I can separate my query into subqueries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex Wordpress query using multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247015/complex-wordpress-query-using-multiple-queries)

Comment: Thanks nbk. Have seen this one before. But I don't think I can split my query into separate queries like in this example.

Comment: yes you can user defined variables are valid for a session or switch to a stored procedure.